# How to match date in a certain format in ruby?

Tags: ruby, matching

I want to go through each line in a file and find a date in format `mm/dd/yyyy`. I tried `scan` and `match`, but I don't think they are working for me. What else can I try? Can I see samples how would you guys do it (using regular expressions)?

Comment: Why is `match` not working?

Comment: Will single-digit months and days have leading zeros?

Comment: Ariam, you may wish to edit your question to include a small part of a typical file and also how you used `scan` and/or `match`.

Answer (score 0):

Test Code:

```
file_data = "with a date 01/02/1900 \n without a date in line\n"
file_data.each_line do |l|
  dt = l.scan(/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/).flatten.first
  puts "Line: #{l} #{dt ? 'with' : 'without'} a date #{dt} in it."
end
```

Result:

```
Line: with a date 01/02/1900
 with a date 01/02/1900 in it.
Line:  without a date in line
 without a date  in it.
```

The regexp may not validate months with 30/31 days and leap years. I just want to help you to study further on this topic.